# How to include OS command with Substitute function in Openedge?

Tags: operating-system, wkhtmltopdf, quotes, openedge, progress-4gl

Im trying to create an PDF via OS-Command in OpenEdge but I hit an error when I run the script.

**Error* : **The command "C: \ Program" is either misspelled or could not be found**

It works perfectly :

> os-command (' "C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
> "V:\V11\WEB\PDF\Name_01.03.2021_14.09.30_da.html"
> "V:\V11\WEB\PDF\Name_01.03.2021_14.09.30_da.pdf" ').

However, when I Include the command in script and run it then I encounter an *error*.

This one doesnt work :

> define variable cmdcommand as char no-undo. cmdcommand = SUBSTITUTE
> (' "C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
> "V:\V11\WEB\PDF\Name_&1_&2_&3.html"
> "V:\V11\WEB\PDF\Name_&1_&2_&3.pdf" ', "01.03.2021", "14.09.30", "da").
> os-command value(cmdcommand).

What did I miss here? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second sample, there's no value in using SUBSTITUTE, as your're not using place holders (&1, &2, ...). What you're doing is basically a straight forward string assignment.

The resulting string looks like this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe""V:\V11\WEB\PDF\Name_01.03.2021_14.09.30_da.html""V:\V11\WEB\PDF\Name_01.03.2021_14.09.30_da.pdf"

- there's an extra space at the beginning
- there's no space between the closing quote of the path to your exe and the first argument.

This here works for me:

```
define variable cmdcommand as char no-undo.

cmdcommand = SUBSTITUTE ('"c:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\winmergeu.exe" &1 &2',
                          "c:\temp\1.txt",
                          "c:\temp\2.txt").

OS-COMMAND silent value(cmdcommand).
```

Due to the use of the SUBSTITUTE function with place holders, this gives me a clean command with a space between the exe path and the first argument.

It works with or without the SILENT option.

Comment: If your code ever needs to run on Linux or Unix it would be a good idea to get into the habit of escaping the backslashes as "~\" rather than using a naked "\".

Comment: Tom, that's pretty unlikely to happen for ALB code trying to run anything from c:\Program Files (x86)\...

Comment: Sure. But it is still a good habit to form.

Answer (score 1):

After having fought with `os-command` for quite some time to get normal errors and output returned, if you are only targeting Windows then it you may find it easier to use the .Net [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) class.

To get you started:

```
define variable oProcess as System.Diagnostics.Process no-undo.
define variable oInfo    as System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo no-undo.

oProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process().
assign 
   oInfo = oProcess:StartInfo
    
   oInfo:FileName         =  "C:~\Program Files (x86)~\winmerge~\winmergeu.exe".
   oInfo:WorkingDirectory =  "session:temp-directory
   oInfo:Arguments        =  substitute(
                                "&1 &2",
                                quoter( "file1.txt" ),
                                quoter( "file2.txt" )
                             )
   .
                
oProcess:Start().
oProcess:WaitForExit().
```

Other useful properties of the [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo) class include:

- CreateNoWindow
- UseShellExecute
- RedirectStandardError
- RedirectStandardOutput